# The register function does not show up after admin.site in my PyCharm Django Development

Tags: django

I am supposed to use `admin.site.register` to register a model to my website, but `register` function does not show up after `admin.site`. There is a `register` function showing up after admin though. Should I use `admin.register` instead of `admin.site.register`?

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Question

admin.site. # register does not show up
```

Comment: What exactly does you mean by “Does not show up”? Doesn’t it “suggest” register or is there an error when you run with “admin.site.register()”?

Comment: If it just doesn’t suggest it, try just running your program anyways, even if it is saying that admin.site.register is not found.

Comment: By show up you mean it doesn't autocomplete it ? You should type `admin.site.register(<Model Name>)` anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that you chosen the right Python Interpreter? Did you install django on that interpreter ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you program in an IDE (For example PyCharm), the IDE can sometimes lose track of all the functions and modules that are loaded. And that can lead to some weird errors while programming, where you for example *can’t see a specific function that you know should be there*, or it just shows errors weird places where there shouldn’t be any. The solution to this is to restart your IDE or to just run your program anyways after you’ve typed in what you think should be right;
in this case: `admin.site.register(<Model Name>)`